# standalone xml and well-formedness

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

As I understand it, well formed xml uses the dtd to:

1. Provide replacement text for internal references.
2. Provide default attribute values
3. Normalize attribute values (seems like a special case of 1)

If a document is declared as standalone, does a missing attribute list declaration or a missing entity declaration have any relevance for well-formedness checking?

More succinctly, does a well-formedness checker care about standalone=yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well-formedness constraint: Entity Declared
>
> In a document without any DTD, a document with only an internal DTD
>   subset which contains no parameter entity references, or a document
>   with "standalone='yes'", for an entity reference that does not occur
>   within the external subset or a parameter entity, the Name given in
>   the entity reference MUST match that in an entity declaration that
>   does not occur within the external subset or a parameter entity,
>   except that well-formed documents need not declare any of the
>   following entities: amp, lt, gt, apos, quot. The declaration of a
>   general entity MUST precede any reference to it which appears in a
>   default value in an attribute-list declaration.
>
> Note that non-validating processors are not obligated to to read and
>   process entity declarations occurring in parameter entities or in the
>   external subset; for such documents, the rule that an entity must be
>   declared is a well-formedness constraint only if standalone='yes'.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-references